# Crash on iOS 11 when using AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, avspeechsynthesizer

Our app uses `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to speak short pieces of text. After the release of iOS 11 we started to see crash reports on Crashlytics in the Apple private class, `AXSpeechManager`:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010

libAXSpeechManager.dylib__61-[AXSpeechManager speechSynthesizer:didStartSpeakingRequest:]_block_invoke + 48
```

While debugging, I can see that this method is called when `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is speaking text. But I cannot reproduce this crash on device or in simulator.

Does anyone has the same issue or has clues what can cause it? Our app allows users to edit text which will be synthesized. Maybe, some users enter text that causes `AXSpeechManager` to crash?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @MohitSingh, not really. Now I think that the reason for crashes may not be connected directly to iOS 11. Code written by previous developer uses the global variable for storing AVSpeechSynthesizer objects that are created for each piece of text. I have rewritten code to have only one instance of AVSpeechSynthesizer but it is too early to say if it helped.

Comment: That might be the case! Just let us here if you find anything useful with time. Probably there are more users struggling with this. Thanks for your reply :)